# Efficient oxidation of KCl to KClO3

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, home-experiment

I am trying to convert $\ce{KCl}$ to $\ce{KClO3}$ through an efficient process.  I realize that I could electrolyze a solution of $\ce{KCl}$ to obtain some $\ce{KClO3}$ as a precipitate, however this seems inefficient as some chlorine will inevitably escape as a gas. Could an oxidizer such as hydrogen peroxide or sulfuric acid achieve this?  I realize that $\ce{Cl-}$ would be oxidized to $\ce{Cl}$ but I thought that there may be a way around that.  What is the best method?